# SelectDateWidget choices

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I would manually like to set the date choices in my form according to my DB data.
Here is a code snippet of the code I am using

```py
DATA_YEARS = ('2017', '2018')
DATA_MONTHS = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12')

class DateForm(forms.Form):
    year = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=DATA_YEARS))
    month = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(months=DATA_MONTHS))
```

However, I reckon SelectDateWidget does not expect to receive these arguments.
If not, how can I implement this properly?

Comment: What's the problem? One thing I've noticed is that you're not using dict for months in this code snippet and Django [SelectDateWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#selectdatewidget) expects dict of months.

Comment: You are right :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. I am developing a form wherein I am asking for date of birth of the user, hence I did this:

```
from django import forms
import datetime

class FeedbackForm(forms.Form):
    user_name = forms.CharField()
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(
            years=range(1980, datetime.date.today().year - 15)
        )
    )
    email_address = forms.EmailField()
```

Note: I have subtracted 15 because I was looking for the date of birth of folks who are at least 15 years of age. You may ignore that.